# Update content with Ajax. How to separate the output in HTML <div>

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, sql-update

I am updating my site content with AJAX by using this method i have found here: https://www.9lessons.info/2009/07/auto-load-refresh-every-10-seconds-with.html

This works very well but according to this tutorial i have to echo the values i want to show as an updated value in the background running "record_count.php". Later all values are shown up in my frontend file "index.php" within the specific `<div id="xxx">`. my problem is now that in my background "record_count.php" i have several values i echo but in need them in separate HTML `<div id="1, 2, ...>` In my example it is **$name** and **$city**. How can i connect the values to a specific HTML `<div id="1, 2, ...>` ? (Please ignore the old query method i have copy/paste here. In my code i am using prepared statements with PDO)

**index.php**

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/
libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function ()
{
$('#load_tweets').load('record_count.php?q=<?php echo $id; ?>').fadeIn("slow");
}, 10000); // refresh every 10000 milliseconds

<body>
<div id="load_tweets"> </div>
</body>

</script>
```

**record_count.php**

```html
<?php
include("db.php");
$search_word=$_GET['q'];
$sql = mysqli_query($db,"Select name, city FROM users where id = $id");
$record_count=mysqli_num_rows($sql);
//Display count.........
echo $city;
echo $name
?>
```

Comment: You are probably better off just returning the data in a usable format (e.g. JSON) and then create the dom elements in javascript. That will give you way more flexibility.

Comment: You want to say that there is no possibility to add a filter or limitation here?

Comment: I'm sorry, then I'm probably not following your question correctly